# Blackberry HttpConnection prob to run in simulator

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection, getresponse

I want call a url and get the response data from the url from my Blackberry App. For that, I am using `HttpConnection`. Here is the code I am using:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.ContentConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestApp extends UiApplication {

   private MainScreen _mainScreen;

   private static TestApp _app;

   public TestApp(){
       _mainScreen = new MainScreen();

       LabelField testField = new LabelField("hello world");

       _mainScreen.add(testField);

       pushScreen(_mainScreen);

       HttpConnection c = null;
       DataInputStream dis = null;

       try {
        System.out.println("0");
        c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com");

        System.out.println("1");
        int rc = c.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("2");
        if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
        }
        System.out.println("3");
        dis = c.openDataInputStream();
        System.out.println("4");
        int len = (int)c.getLength();
        if (len > 0) {
            byte[] data = new byte[len];
            dis.readFully(data);
        } else {
            int ch;
            while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
                //...
            }
        }
       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }finally {

           try {
                if (dis != null)
                    dis.close();
                if (c != null)
                    c.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }

   } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         _app = new TestApp();
         _app.enterEventDispatcher();

  }  
}
```

When I try to run the code in simulator, I am getting '0', then '1' and after that after long time 'No stack trace' is appearing in debug window and as soon as the text is appearing, the level app with the text becomes visible in the simulator screen. There is no problem in the internet connection in simulator, I have set up the Wi-Fi and I have tested that I can open any website in the browser. What is problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDS has to start for internet access, it will work as interface between Simulator and desktop internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to read about networking in BlackBerry infrastructure. Please take a look to BlackBerry documentation.

To make your code works quickly - just add suffixes to requested urls - ";interface=wifi" to run over WiFi or ";deviceside=false" to reach over radio. So your orignal url will be "http://www.google.com;deviceside=false" or "http://www.google.com;interface=wifi".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should show the screen and then spawn a worker thread to do the connection. Anyway, you should use `ConnectionFactory` in OS >= 5.0 to avoid the "hell of suffixes" it takes to manage this in prior versions. Also note that a failed connection will usually take 2 minutes to timeout.

Comment: You really should (no maybe) run the http fetch on a separate thread. What you`re doing is causing the event thread (and therefore the OS) to block waiting for getResponseCode() to return. Which it may never do since you have blocked the OS.

Answer (score 0):

when you open http connection in blackberry your url 
`"http://www.google.com"`
should also contain connection suffix.so ur url become of the form
`"http://www.google.com"+connectionsuffix`

if you have normal gprs pack then your url become
"http://www.google.com"+";deviceside=true"